# Python cx_Freeze for two or more python files (modules)

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, exe, cx-freeze

There are example to build executable using one py file(module) as given [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120622213400/http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html) I have about 4 py files(modules), I would like to build executable which should include all the py files.

How to build python executable when we have more then one python modules ?

Example from [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120622213400/http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html)

```
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
        name = "hello",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "the typical 'Hello, world!' script",
        executables = [Executable("hello.py")])
```

This has hello.py if I have two files like hello1.py and hello2.py ?

Thanks

Comment: Are the different Python files separate scripts that should each have an exe, or are they one script that is run and several modules that are imported?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `hello.py`file import those files - `hello1.py` and `hello2.py`, then this line:

```
executables = [Executable("hello.py")])
```

is quite enough.

But if any of those files are separate script file, then you should do like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
        name = "hello",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "the typical 'Hello, world!' script",
        executables = [Executable("hello.py"), Executable("hello1.py"), Executable("hello2.py")]
)
```

It will create 3 `.exe` files, for each one of your scripts.