# How do I convert my pygame program which has multiple python scripts and images to a exe?

Tags: python, pygame, exe

I have 3 python scripts and many images in folders and tmx files which I want to make it as a single .exe . I wasnt able to find how to convert multiple python scripts and folders to single exe. I was only able to find cxfreeze and similar things for a single python script. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a setup.py file in cxfreeze. You have to pass multiple pyhton files as list in cxfreeze executables. Refere this thread -

[Python cx_Freeze for two or more python files (modules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172483/python-cx-freeze-for-two-or-more-python-files-modules)

For separate files like images, you have to include those files explicitly. Below is an example which worked for me on one of the project -

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['os', 'tkinter', 'matplotlib.backends.backend_svg', 'subprocess'],
                     'namespace_packages': ['mpl_toolkits'],
                     'include_files':['input3.json', 'SF.xlsx', 'SF logo.ico', 'Operative Temperature.pkl',
                                      'Rect_icon.png', 'Soltissim logo.png', 'SF full logo.jpg', 'IES logo.jpg']}

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

setup ( name = 'Soltissim',
        version = '2',
        description = 'SF GUI',
        options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable('Soltissim.py', base=base, icon='SF logo.ico'),
                       Executable('SF_English.py', base=base, icon='SF logo.ico'),
                       Executable('SF_French.py', base=base, icon='SF logo.ico')])
```

Furhter, if you want to create a build from setup which can be then used in program like inno, use following command in terminal - python setup.py build

If you want to create a simple windows installer directly from setup, use - python setup.py bdist_msi

Answer (score 2):

You can add external files to your pyinstaller exe by using `add-data`. An example I'm using for one of my pygame games:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --clean --name "MyGame" --icon="images/icon.ico" --add-data "images/*.png:images" --add-data "sounds/*.mp3:sounds" --add-data "sounds/*.wav:sounds" --add-data "fonts/*.ttf:fonts" main.py
```

Comment: Does that images/*.png:images add all the images in the folder?