# Compiling pygame multiple scripts with images and music files

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

I've been trying to compile my game. I tried using cx_Freeze, and pyinstaller. It has 3 pygame python scripts, 5 music files, 3   PNG file formats

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I compile my pygame scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the full example here in how to include files and multiple Python files in cxfreeze setup -

[How do I convert my pygame program which has multiple python scripts and images to a exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362899/how-do-i-convert-my-pygame-program-which-has-multiple-python-scripts-and-images/62556787?r=SearchResults#62556787)