# cx_Freeze: Python error main script. Module not found error: no module named pygments.lexers.python

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pygments

I am trying to create a file `.exe` from a `.py` file with `cx_Freeze`. I had successifully build the setup file but when I run the `.exe` file, it returns me this error:

-I tried to install again Python

-I tried to update pygments but it says that the requirements are already satisfied

Any suggestions? Help this poor newborn programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually include missing module in cx freeze packages. Refer answer here for example code -

[How do I convert my pygame program which has multiple python scripts and images to a exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362899/how-do-i-convert-my-pygame-program-which-has-multiple-python-scripts-and-images/62556787?r=SearchResults#62556787)