# Generate an executable from python project

Tags: python, exec, executable, cx-freeze, generate

I need to generate an executable from a python project containing multiple folders and files.
I tried to work with library *cx_Freeze*, but only worked for a single file project.

Can you tell me how to do please?

Comment: maybe try pyinstaller? https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172483/python-cx-freeze-for-two-or-more-python-files-modules

Comment: @PeterWood Read my answer. It has more detail into how cx_Freeze works, including how to include folders inside the exe but not outside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pyinstaller. just run
`pip install pyinstaller` and then open the folder the file is located in with shell and run `pyinstaller --onefile FILE.py` where file is the name of the python file that should be run when the exe is run

Comment: I think I tried pyinstaller once and it didn't work because it wasn't in PATH. Besides, pyinstaller looks more limited. cx_Freeze can work without having Python scripts inside PATH because you can make a build script and import cx_Freeze then do `python build.py build`

Comment: Thanks it almost works. With my code.exe, my links between my files don't work. I did an interface and when I push a button on it to open another one, it doesn't find the file (it says because of the path), but it worked when I tested my code.py in a terminal

Comment: I was hoping for something new here. `pyinstaller` is great for single files. My project has the usual setup: code folder, .venv folder, lots of files, etc. It's a flask server and when I run the executable it reports `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'`. Needless to say, the non-compiled version works fine. Are there any details _assumed_ in here, like `PYTHONPATH`, whether to activate the venv or where to be when you run this? Better question: did you actually try this?

Answer (score 2):

Running pyinstaller on your "main" python file should work, as PyInstaller automatically imports any dependencies (such as other python files) that you use.

Comment: Pyinstaller does seem to import any python dependencies. However, you will need to move your assets folder (images etc.), keeping the same internal directory structure of the assets folder, inside the folder where your exe file is located.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do:

Create a build.py file with instructions like this:

```
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("main.py")] # The main script

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="Platform Designer", # The name of the exe
    options={"build_exe": {
        "packages": ["pygame"], # Packages used inside your exe
        "include_files": ["data", "instructions.md"], # Files in the exe's directory
        "bin_path_includes": ["__custom_modules__"]}}, # Files to include inside the exe
    executables=executables
)
```

Run in command prompt:

- `python build.py build` to build a exe
- `python build.py bdist_msi` to build an msi installer

Make sure to remove the `build` and `dist` folders whenever you're updating your exe or msi.